# Parallel integration testing with SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, xunit

Wanted Result: Run integration tests in parallel with entity framework configured to use some kind of database that enforces constraints.

Current Situation: I have a project with some integration tests, and by that I mean test set up with `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>`. Currently I use it with EF Core setup to use In Memory Database

```
 protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            ConfigureWebHostBuilder(builder);
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => 
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("testDb");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                    options.EnableDetailedErrors();
                    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
                });
            });
        }
```

While this works, the problem is that it doesn't enforce SQL queries and I already ran in multiple cases where integration tests show the feature works, but when trying to reproduce it with actual project running and having EF connected to SQL Server database, the feature fails because of some failed database constraint.

Ideas:

- At first I thought of using SQLite in memory database. Didn't work, I think it's some concurrency issue, because at the start of every test case, I wipe the database with `.EnsureDeleted()` `.EnsureCreated()` `.Migrate()`
- Then SQLite with files with random names. Didn't work, because I couldn't manage to wipe out internal DbContext Cache. I was sure that file was recreated and clean, but DbContext simply had cached entities.
- Finally after some migrations I released that I wouldn't probably be able to use SQLite at all, because it doesn't support a lot of migration types (Removing FK, altering a column, etc.)/